Insert pictures and rotate them according to the page number
\documentclass{beamer}

\usebackgroundtemplate%
{% your any picture
\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth, angle=\arabic{page}, origin=c]{example-image}}

\logo{\includegraphics[width=0.8cm, angle=\arabic{page}, origin=c]{example-image}}% your any picture

\begin{document}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\frame{\arabic{page}}
\end{document}

I get interesting results with this code, but the parameter of angle is just the number of pages, I would like to multiply it by a factor, like 37
And I want to keep the center of the image still at a fixed location, once rotated it will always move

You can use example-image that everyone has with their TeX installation.  But is your image square in shape, or will rotation cause the dimensions to change?

Thanks for reminding me, I had no knownadge about example-image, I guess the reason why the center moves is because the image cannot be a circle

\value{page} is a count, so \the\numexpr 3*\value{page}\relax should work.  Axtually, \arabic{count} will work, but will convert the count to text and back again.

@John Kormylo yes, its works. Not sure if there is a better way

The TeX version would be \count1=\count0 \multiply\count1 by 3 \number\count1
